# Save table sorting after page reload

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have webpage with table and javascript that sorts columns (js I found in google). This page have refresh option (every 30 secs). I need to save table sorting after refresh. How can i do it?

Comment: please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've tried to add .datateble ({ stateSave:true});

Answer (score 0):

You must have some sort of a database.
A popular one is MySQL.

Remember, javascript is browser-side (client-side) language,
and so it is not capable of saving data. (without using HTML5 storage or cookie).

If you want to save it using cookie or html5 storage, look:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to PHP (at least you've tagged this with PHP) and you don't need to save the sorting permanently, try using sessions.

In essence:

1. Set table sorting with JavaScript on the page where the table is displayed (this is what you currently have).
2. [Call PHP via AJAX](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-javascript.php), submit the selected sorting method/type as a parameter.
3. PHP script receives the POST and initiates or reloads a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) (`session_start()`).
4. PHP saves the sorting method into the session `$_SESSION['table_sort_method'] = $sort_method;` (`$sort_method` should be received from the AJAX POST, `'table_sort_method'` is just an example array key name).
5. Now when the page viewer returns to the table page, you can lookup the sorting method from `$_SESSION` and use it when the table is initially displayed.

Remember to call `session_start()` before any HTML is output to get access to the correct `$_SESSION` data.

If you need this to be permanent, you can use the above logic but replace the PHP session related parts with database interactions of your choice.